# Compute limits using central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk, central-limit-theorem

I want to find the limit of expressions such as: $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{n} \le \epsilon) $. I do not know how to proceed.

Using the central limit theorem, I can rewrite the expression: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|S_{n}|\le n \cdot \epsilon) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(- n \epsilon \le |S_{n}| \le n \epsilon) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-x^{2}/2}=1$$

Is that correct?

If so, how do I proceed in the case  $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{n} =0) $?

Your support is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Best, Jolle

Comment: What is $S_n$ ?

Comment: $S_{n}$ is a simple random walk which means $p=0.5$.

Comment: What is $p$ ? You need to be more precise when you write mathematical content

Comment: This results from the fact that we are dealing with a simple random walk. It means that $ P(X_k=1)=P(X_k=-1)=0.5$. In other words, $S_n$ is the sum of n Bernoulli experiments and therefore binomial distributed.

Comment: By CLT, you know that $P(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\in A) \to_n \int_A f(x)dx$ where $f$ is the density of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. So the right scale to see $S_n$ is $\sqrt{n}$. Naturaly, $\frac{S_n}{n}$ should go to $0$. In the other case, $S_n$ is zero should mean something in term of event of $X_1,...,X_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Does this mean I have to do something like:
$P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{n} \le \epsilon) = P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}} \le \epsilon) = P(\frac{|S_{n}|}{\sqrt{n}} \le \sqrt{n} \cdot \epsilon)$? In this case, $\sqrt{n} \cdot \pm \epsilon \to \pm \infty$ for $n \to \infty$. Is this correct?